# How can I compute the coordinates of an Equilateral Triangle?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, graphics2d

The goal is to tesselate a plane using either equilateral triangles, squares, or hexagons, determined by an integer read from a file. The side length is also given by reading an integer from a file. I've done it for squares, but the triangle has me stumped. I've been trying to use `drawPolygon`. I assume the side length will correlate to the distance from point a to point b to point c, but i really have no clue as to how to find the coordinates.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawShapes extends JPanel {

    private int shape;  //user choice of which shape to draw
    private int sideLength; //user choice of what length to draw the sides

    public DrawShapes(int shapeChoice, int sideChoice) {
        shape = shapeChoice;
        sideLength = sideChoice;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                switch(shape) {
                    case 3: //Draws triangles
                        //int[] x = 
                        //int[] y = 
                        //int[] n =
                        g.setColor(Color.green);
                        //g.drawPolygon(x,y,n);
                        break;

                    case 4: //Draws squares
                        g.setColor(Color.blue);
                        g.drawRect(sideLength*i, sideLength*j, sideLength, sideLength);
                        break;

                    case 6: //Draws hexagons
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a math question. Assuming you are using equilateral triangles, the height of an equilateral triangle is equal to `sqrt(3) * base`. Also, to make equilateral triangles tesselate, they alternate up/down, etc.

So if the side length is `sidelength`, and the first coordinate is `(0,0)`, to draw the first triangle, do:

```
g.drawLine(0, 0, sidelength, 0); // the top
g.drawLine(0, 0, sidelength/2, sidelength/2 * sqrt(3)); // left side
g.drawLine(sidelength, 0, sidelength/2, sidelength/2 * sqrt(3)); // right side
```

To draw the upside down triangle, you only need to draw two more sides:

```
g.drawLine(sidelength, sidelength/2 * sqrt(3), 3 * sidelength/2, sidelength/2 * sqrt(3));
g.drawLine(sidelength, 0, 3 * sidelength/2, sidelength/2 * sqrt(3));
```

HOWEVER, this is not the best way to do it (draw each triangle by hand). It's better to just draw big lines as the lines are all attached to each other.

```
private static final double srqtThree = sqrt(3)/2d;
private Dimension d = new Dimension();
private int rootThree;
public DrawShapes(int sideLength) {
    rootThree = (int) sideLength * sqrt(3)/2d;
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    getSize(d);
    int y = 0;
    while(y < d.height) {
        // Draw the horizontal line
        g.drawLine(0, y, d.width, y);
        y = y + rootThree;
    }

    // Figure this out mostly yourself, but now you draw the angled sides.
    // Use this to get started. This is the down-to-right line
    g.drawLine(0, 0, d.width / sqrtThree, d.height);
    g.drawLine(sideLength, 0, sideLength + (d.width / sqrtThree), d.height);-

    // Now draw the down-to-left line
}
```

**Note:** you may have to do a lot of size bounds checking to get this to work correctly. But it would be faster than drawing each triangle by hand.

Comment: This doesn't even seem correct. The height of an equilateral triangle needs to be LESS than the base. sqrt(3) > 1 so this can't be right.

Answer (score 1):

**For the bottom left corner of the Triangle to be 0,0 the 3 coordinates need to be:**

0, 0  `(bottom left)`

sidelength, 0  `(bottom right)`

sidelength/2, sin(60)*sidelength `(tip)`

**To tesselate, the next triangle in the row will have**

sidelength/2, sin(60)*sidelength `(top left)`

3*sidelength / 2, sin(60)*sidelength `(top right)`

sidelength, 0 `(tip, which is now on the bottom)`

Then it's really just a matter of adding an x, y to each point to move it along.

Answer (score 0):

Create an, upright, equilateral triangle with a side of `10` and an origin, centered, of `(50, 50)`.

```
g.fillPolygon(createTriange(50, 50, 10, false));
```

```java
private Polygon createPolygon(float x, float y, float side, boolean invert) {
    float xOff = side / 2f;
    float yOff = (float) (xOff * Math.sqrt(3));

    float r1 = 1f / 3f;
    float r2 = 2f / 3f;

    if (invert) { yOff *= -1; }

    Point2D.Float top   = new Point2D.Float(x,        y - (yOff * r2));
    Point2D.Float left  = new Point2D.Float(x - xOff, y + (yOff * r1));
    Point2D.Float right = new Point2D.Float(x + xOff, y + (yOff * r1));

    int xCoords[] = { (int) top.x, (int) left.x, (int) right.x, (int) top.x };
    int yCoords[] = { (int) top.y, (int) left.y, (int) right.y, (int) top.y };

    return new Polygon(xCoords, yCoords, xCoords.length);
}
```